# Could not get UEFI db error after suddern power off

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, disk, disk-usage

I have installed windows 10 and later I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as duel boot. Both works as expected.

After some days while working on Ubuntu I shutdown the machine and since it takes more time I power off using power button. When I started back (Ubuntu) there was an error "Could not get UEFI db list". But Ubuntu got started after long time and it is very slow.

Then I restarted and tried Windows 10 and it is also takes more time to boot and after boot it is very slow. It shows 100% disk usage in task manager.

I also tried to boot with a live Ubuntu Live USB disk and works well. It also shows me all the partitions and I can access files on my disk. I also tried to install Ubuntu again and it got stucked when loading the disk partition table.

Can you please help me to resolve this problem?